# How to remove warning in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working on an app and I am using `bottomTabNavigator` but in mean time I am getting this warning! `( Look like you're passing an inline function for 'Component' prop for the screen 'Feed' (e.g component={()=><SomeComponent/>)). Passing an inline function will cause the component state to be lost on re-render and cause perf issue since it's re-created every render. You can pass the function as children to 'Screen' instead to achieve the desired behaviour.`

I know I am doing something wrong but I didn't figure out what's wrong with my code. I am new to React native, could someone please help me how to solve this warning .

**Code**

```
 return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Home"
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={props => (
              <PharmacyHome
                catId={this.props.navigation.state.params}
                {...props}
              />
            )}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: "Home",
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
              )
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Notifications"
            component={Notifications}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: "Updates",
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
              )
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={Profile}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: "Profile",
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="account"
                  color={color}
                  size={size}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
```

Comment: For anyone else hitting this page from google search : the error message will also come, if you name your screen "component" even in its own the source file, e.g.: "
const component = (props) => { .. }; export default component; ". This is becasue react-navigation code actually checks if the name of the component is "component". See here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/packages/core/src/useNavigationBuilder.tsx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Quick Solution**

Move your component definition into a separate line of code

```
        component={props => (
          <PharmacyHome
            catId={this.props.navigation.state.params}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
```

**Instead**

```
const YourComponent = props => (
  <PharmacyHome catId={this.props.navigation.state.params} {...props} />
);

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={YourComponent}
```

**Explanation**

Components use **reference identity** to determine when to re-renders ... so by passing component-definition as a prop, you're forcing it to create a new-object as a component with each-render ... causing unnecessary-re-renders for `Tab.Screen`, and no-state will be preserved between renders for `YourComponent`

Comment: Not sure what is the difference, can someone please explain?

Answer (score 16):

If you need to pass a non-serializable props, such as a function, then you can do [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props) instead:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {props => <PharmacyHome catId={this.props.navigation.state.params} {...props} />
</Stack.Screen>
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer

Comment: I get the same error doing this :/

Answer (score 6):

The other answers do the job but these solutions have severe performance issues if your screen has a lot of components, in my case I had a Flatlist with elements ever increasing on scrolling.

So I figured out a solution. You can use the property 'children' to pass an element type jsx like instead of the property 'component'.

I'm using react navigation 5.x

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    children={() => <PharmacyHome catId={this.props.navigation.state.params}/>}
    .
    .
    .
/>
```

This had no performance issues compared to what I was getting when trying for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by passing what I wanted through **params instead of props**.
For you, it would look like this:

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={PharmacyHome}
    initialParams={{ catId: this.props.navigation.state.params }}
/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will throw a warning if you're trying to pass serializable values as params. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61936715/2891356) for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, from the documentation:

Use a render callback for the screen instead of specifying a component prop:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props