# React native pass function through props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am new to react native and I'm having some trouble passing a function from a parent class to a child class

```
//Child class
const AppDrawer = ({update_recent}) => {
     update_recent("Notification");
}

//Parent class
const App: () => React$Node = () => {    
    const [recent, setRecent] = useState("Home");

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
       SplashScreen.hide();
    });

    return (
       <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Application" component={AppDrawer} update_recent={setRecent}/> //Pass in set recent function to child class.
        <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} recent_page={recent}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm passing setRecent to AppDrawer so the AppDrawer class is able to edit the `recent` variable. Please let me know how I should do this.

[image: Warning Picture]

Comment: you can give more information

Comment: you using javascript or typescript ?

Comment: If you want to pass a function to your component from the Main Root Navigation. You should pass a prop `initialParams` so it should be like that: `initialParams={{ update_recent: setRecent }}` 
And you can get this function from navigation state in Application for example

Comment: This is in JS in my App.js file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove warning in React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586470/how-to-remove-warning-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

**you can try something like**

```js
  <Stack.Screen name="Application" component={()=><AppDrawer update_recent={setRecent}/>}/> //Pass in set recent function to child class.
```

in component instead of directly passing AppDrawer you can pass an arrow function that returns AppDrawer component while passing `setRecent` as a prop `update_recent`.

---

### **updates**

### Use a render callback for the screen instead of specifying a component prop:

```js
  <Stack.Screen name="Application" component={(props)=><AppDrawer {..props} update_recent={setRecent}/>}/> //Pass in set recent function to child class.
```

See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but I am getting a warning. I've attached a picture to my post showing the warning that I'm getting. Can you please help me get rid of this warning? Thank you!

Comment: @KevinWu 
Use a render callback for the screen instead of specifying a component prop:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Application" component={(props)=><AppDrawer {..props} update_recent={setRecent}/>}/> //Pass in set recent function to child class.

```javascript
See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props